# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Policy_payment

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1452

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InQML.png)I have created these tables in phpmyadmin

**Payment table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Payment; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Payment (
pay_id int(5) NOT NULL, 
number int(25) default NULL, 
amount decimal(20,2) default NULL,
CONSTRAINT Payment_pk_payid 
PRIMARY KEY (pay_id) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Policy_payment table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Policy_payment;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Policy_payment( 
id int(5) NOT NULL, 
policy_id int(5) NOT NULL, 
pay_id int(5) NOT NULL, 
date date default NULL, 
CONSTRAINT Policy_payment_pk_id_policyid_payid 
    PRIMARY KEY (id,policy_id,pay_id),
CONSTRAINT Policy_payment_fk_policyid 
    FOREIGN KEY (policy_id)
    REFERENCES Policy (policy_id), 
CONSTRAINT Policy_payment_fk_payid
    FOREIGN KEY (pay_id) 
    REFERENCES Payment (pay_id) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**So when i try to insert the the values in Policy_payment table, it gives a #1452 error. What am i doing wrong?**

**--Dumping data for table Policy_payment**

```
INSERT INTO Policy_payment (
id, policy_id, pay_id, date) 
VALUES
('70111', '88881', '20001', '2019-01-10'), 
('70112', '88882', '20002', '2019-09-25'), 
('70113', '88883', '20003', '2019-04-18'), 
('70114', '88884', '20004', '2020-11-11'), 
('70115', '88885', '20005', '2020-06-23'), 
('70116', '88886', '20006', '2021-12-11'), 
('70117', '88887', '20007', '2021-08-20'), 
('70118', '88888', '20008', '2018-03-04'), 
('70119', '88889', '20009', '2018-03-20'), 
('70110', '88810', '20010', '2016-02-09');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obBIg.png)

this is the error
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`S11185754`.`Policy_payment`, CONSTRAINT `Policy_payment_fk_payid` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_id`) REFERENCES `Payment` (`pay_id`))

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a search engine with the phrase "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" because this gives lots and lots of answers which will fit your exact question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a record with a pay_id that doesn't match any record in the payment table i.e. exactly what the error message says.